# Bootstrap select2 doesn't open in modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I'm trying to use bootstrap SELECT2 plugin inside dynamic modal content but it doesn't works.

this is the script to open the modal:

index.php (here i call to custom-select.min.js and custom-select.min.css)

```
$(document).on("click", ".manage-modal", function(e){

    var link = "form_modal.php";

    $('.modal-body').load(link,function(){
        $('#manage-modal').modal({show:true});
    });

});
```

HTML part -

```
<a href='#' class='manage-modal' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#manage-modal" data-act="new">OPEN MODAL BUTTON</a>

<div id="manage-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is part of my Modal content (form_modal.php):

```
<form>
    <select name="contries" class="form-control select2">
        <option value='FR'>FRANCE</option>
        <option value='SP'>SPAIN</option>
        <option value='USA'>USA</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".select2").select2({ width: 'resolve' });
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the dropdownParent setting may be helpful.

Try to do it in below way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".select2").select2({ dropdownParent: $('#selectParent'), width: 'resolve' });
});
```

and

```html
<form>
    <div id="selectParent">
        <select name="countries" class="form-control select2">
            <option value='FR'>FRANCE</option>
            <option value='SP'>SPAIN</option>
            <option value='USA'>USA</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure about the `<select2...` ?

Comment: not particularly for the version you are using. I use Select2 4.0.5 version and execute it like that.

Comment: you wrote `<select2 name="contries" class="form-control select2">` check the first characterless - it's `<select2` (with the number "2").

Comment: I updated my answer. You can have a look at [Dropdown placement](https://select2.org/dropdown#dropdown-placement) part of the documentation.